# How to add relation on microservices on Prisma using NestJS?

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, nestjs, prisma

Schema on User Management service:

```
model User {
  id                 String    @id @default(uuid())
  username           String    @unique
  email              String    @unique
  password           String
}
```

Schema on File management service:

```
model File {
  id               String   @id @default(uuid())
  user_id          String
  user             User     @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  file_name        String
  file_description String
  file_url         String
  file_hash        String
}
```

My user management service and file management service is different repository using Nest Js, Thank You!

I want to add relation on file model to user model

Comment: Which tool are you using to merge multiple schema files? As Prisma doesn't support splitting schema file natively.

Answer (score 0):

To add a relation between the File and User models in your Prisma setup with NestJS, you'll need to perform the following steps:

1. Connect to the appropriate Prisma service(s) from your NestJS application(s).
2. Make sure that the User and File models in your Prisma schema have the necessary fields for the relation, as you have defined above.
3. In your NestJS application, create a service that retrieves the appropriate user for each file, based on the user_id field. You can use the prisma-client package to query the Prisma API for the relevant data.
4. In your NestJS controller(s), use the service from step 3 to fetch the relevant data and return it in the API response.

Here's an example of what the service from step 3 might look like:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class FilesService {
  private prisma = new PrismaClient();

  async getFilesWithUser() {
    const files = await this.prisma.file.findMany({
      include: {
        user: true,
      },
    });
    return files;
  }
}
```

And here's an example of what the controller:

```js
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FilesService } from './files.service';

@Controller('files')
export class FilesController {
  constructor(private readonly filesService: FilesService) {}

  @Get()
  async getFilesWithUser() {
    return this.filesService.getFilesWithUser();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i mean for the schema